# Try/Catch using lots of memory on exceptions in php

Tags: php, laravel, memory

For a particular page on a website, I was tasked to create a 'tables view' so that the site admins could see/add/edit/delete data from our tables. Since our database is riddled with foreign keys and I'm somewhat new at this (php + laravel), my implementation was as follows:

- Check which foreign keys exist for this table.
- For each of those keys:

  - Load all the table (for that key) into an array `mapping` (key/value pair)
  - Go through all of the data to-be-transformed, and transform it using `mapping`
- return

I did this to avoid multiple calls to the db, especially since the other tables were relatively small (so there were many repeated values).

Here's the problem I faced: In some instances, over long ranges, we were getting a memory exception (ie all memory consumed). After debugging, I found that my 12 MB of data is using 1.2GB of memory as a peak! I went through my function to figure out what's causing it, and I found the culprit:

```
    // apply mapping to all entries

    if($changed_value == true) {
        // for $i in count(data_column). $col is the foreign key (id) in the $raw_data.
             try {
                 $final_data[$i]->{$new_col_name} = $mapping[$raw_data[$i]->{$col}];
             } catch (\Exception $e) {
                 $final_data[$i]->{$new_col_name} = $raw_data[$i]->{$col};
             }
    }
```

I didn't want the load times to be long, so I didn't check if the id exists in the mapping, opting to instead wrap it in a try-catch and just put the id as is if it fails (ie without mapping the id to the value). The memory footprint before this loop was only 24MB, and it increased to around 240MB after it, **but only when the catch happened often**. I fixed this problem by simply checking if the data was null before applying the mapping, and the max memory used went down from > 1GB to < 40MB.

I have obviously solved the problem, but I don't understand why it happened especially since the extra memory was removed after for the next foreign key (best bet: on exception, either the stack trace is stored for reasons, or the program is stored as an entry point).

So as for the question:

1. Why does this happen? Where are other cases where it could happen so I can be aware of it in advance?

Comment: Exceptions take up memory, they are objects after all. So I guess someone assumed you would not generate 1000's of them., As an exception assumes things are going wrong and most times they would be used to tidy up and exit.

Comment: I'm not 100% on laravel but I'm certain it works in much the same way as symfony/doctrine which will build an optimal query based on what eventually is required for the request, it will also cache as much as possible to cut down on memory required. What you are doing is trying to work around something that has already been built in to save yourself from doing what you are doing. In doing do I feel you are more than likely hydrating many more objects than is actually required. Instead you should try leaving laravel to worry about whether a relationship exists.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes I know that exceptions are objects as well, however since their scope is bound by the `for` loop over `$i`, shouldn't the object be unset once the loop reaches completion?

Comment: @Doug except this query is no longer in the database. To avoid excessive calls I extracted the table data into a hash map (`mapping`) and used it instead. I wasn't entirely sure whether lookup for an index inside the array would be in `O(1)`, since I read somewhere that you can't rely on that being the case all the time, and I didn't want to have an `O(n^3)` loop on a webpage!! Hence the try-catch seemed to be the smarter idea at the time.

Comment: What PHP is this? (7 or 5.*)

Comment: @EmadY Instead of mapping / whatever use cache! And also investigate how database itself does caching (its way clever than you think). This seems to be a clear example of over-engineering.

Comment: @EmadY As an exception is available all the way up the heirarcy all the way to the outer scope, I dont think your idea of a for loop scope can be true

Comment: @RiggsFolly well that makes things even more complicated doesn't it? Since my functions goes along the lines of : `foreach $col in $cols { for $i in range { // exception generated -- persists across loops } // exception still takes up memory here -- but does not persist to next iteration } // exception memory cleared` so why would it persist across the inner `for` (`$i`), and thus exist when we go out of scope of it, but not persist across the multiple `foreach` (`$col`)? That's whats' confusing me.